# How to dynamically set fieldLabel value in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

I want to achieve a situation where my **fieldLabel** values come from store. Store has the values I need, but I can't figure out how to set these values to fieldLabel.

Let's say I have some block:

```
items: [{
  name: 'someName',
  fieldLabel: 'someFieldLabel'
}]
```

**someName** in name field comes from store and works as expected.

**someFieldLabel** value in fieldLabel field is present in store but it shows literally 'someFieldLabel', not the value from store.

Any suggestions how to make this work dynamically with values from store?

Answer (score 0):

```
items: [{
  itemId: 'someField'
  name: 'someName',
  fieldLabel: 'someFieldLabel'
}];
```

on store load function

```
 var somefield = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('field[itemId=someField]');
    somefield[0].setFieldLabel('dynamic_field_label');
```

Comment: Component query would require an index as Ext.ComponentQuery returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code from a fiddle on how to change the fieldLabel dynamically.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Dynamic Set Field Label',
            layout: 'vbox',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                itemId: 'lblItem',
                fieldLabel: 'Testing',
                margin: '0 0 20 0'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Set Field Label',
                handler: function (btn) {
                    // alert('button presssed');
                    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#lblItem')[0].setFieldLabel('New Label');
                }
            }]
        })
    }
});
```

You can see it working [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2rnd).

Note: Using Ext.ComponentQuery it will return an Array of objects meeting the query requirements. You need to specify index to obtain a single object.

```
store.load({
  callback: function (records) {
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#lblItem')
  }
})
```